# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr) won't output HDMI or boot

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, video

I have a custom PC with Windows 10 installed. I installed [Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) LTS into dualboot three days ago, but I'm unable to boot into it. When I start up the computer the [GRUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB) bootloader shows up and everything seems fine (I can also boot into Windows no problem), but if I choose to boot into Ubuntu then the monitor stops getting HDMI input.

How do I fix the problem?

PS: I'm not sure if the system boots, but it doesn't output video or doesn't boot at all.

Answer (score 0):

When you are in the GRUB menu, hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> and remove the kernel options "quiet" and "splash". This should give you the kernel boot messages. It may give a hint to your problem.

It is highly likely that there is an issue with the graphics driver. You could also try to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> after you have a blank screen. This could give you a text-based login prompt. Once logged in, have a look at the file `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`. One way to view the file is like this:

```
more /var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

Comment: I did as you said but the TAB doesnt seem to be doing anything. I also tried CTRL +ALT + F1 and im getting the following message :

[    2.168299] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] No catching mode page found
[    2.168316] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[    7.006293] nouveau E[    PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] failed to load fuc409c 
[    7.012191] nouveau E[        PFIFO][0000:01:00.0] unsupported engines 0x00000001
[    7.012191] nouveau E[          DRM] failed to create kernel channel, -22

but after that PC boots into Ubuntu normally (only if i press ctrl + alt + f1)

Comment: nouveau is the open source graphics driver, and for some reason it has trouble running on your PC. Installing the nvidia driver might help.

Comment: Thank you for your help :) after instaling the nvidia driver everything works fine.